# SSRS conditional picture symbol

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, conditional-statements, symbols

I have an SSRS report with several columns in a simple table. When a column value is 'T' I want an picture of a tick and when the column value is 'X' I want a picture of a cross.

Can someone show me how to do this if it is possible. I have the two images saved.

Comment: Are you looking to have the picture in the tablix cell or outside of the tablix? What version of SSRS are you using?

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2008. and yes the pictures should be inside the cell. Its replacing the letter T and X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to import the pictures you want in the report data pane. Right click on images and click add. Select your picture and repeat for the second.

Delete the data field from the tablix. Place an image object in the desired field. Right click on the image object and select image properties. The last field in the general tab is titled "Use this image:". Click the "fx" button to open the expression editor. Below is an expression that evaluates a field and selects an image based on the value. The switch statement evaluates the list of expressions and returns an object corresponding to the first expression in the list that is true. "cross" and "tick" refer to the names of the images imported.

```
=switch(Fields!A.Value = "x", "cross", Fields!A.Value = "t", "tick")
```